# Check value between two tables (MS ACCESS)

Tags: sql, ms-access, vlookup, contains, exists

I have two table:

**table1:
colName**

```
values: Ford, Audi, Opel
```

**table2:
colNewName**

```
values: 87 Ford Carl, one9 Audi, _12br Opel 45X
```

How to write query, to check if values from table1 exist into table2?

**expect Result**:

```
table1  table2            Result
Ford    "87 Ford Car"     True
Audi    "one9 Audi"       True
Opel    "_12br Opel 45X"  True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple select query will do:

```sql
SELECT 
    table1.colName, 
    table2.colNewName, 
    table2.colNewName Is Not Null As Result
FROM 
    table1 
LEFT JOIN 
    table2 
    ON table2.colNewName Like "*" & table1.colName & "*"
```